# Is it an appropriate forum to ask my question

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question regarding a mobile game, Hustle Castle. I haven't found the answer to it when googling and I have poor experience from the dedicated forum since previously.

Usually, I'd just ask away here **but** I noticed that the tag for Hustle Castle wasn't found by the autocomplete function and it got me uncertain.

Is it OK to ask such a question on Arcade and if so, what tag should I go for?